Coral board : cannot resolve warning
newbie just started figuring out the coral board.
I'm following the guide link
once I got to the Update point,
sudo apt-get update
I get the following warnings

Hit:6 https://mendel-linux.org/apt/eagle-bsp-enterprise eagle InRelease
Hit:7 https://mendel-linux.org/apt/eagle eagle InRelease
Hit:8 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable InRelease
Hit:9 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt mendel-eagle-bsp-enterprise InRelease
Hit:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt mendel-eagle InRelease
Reading package lists... Done


W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/source/Sources' as repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt mendel-eagle-bsp-enterp
rise InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/source/Sources' as repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable In
Release' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/source/Sources' as repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt mendel-eagle InRelease'
 does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)

and when i try upgrading,
sudo apt-get upgrade
nothing gets upgraded
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

is it ok to ignore?
I tried some test code, and it seemed like it's running just fine.
I wonder if it did not skip, it might have upgraded some of the packages??
currently, package installed related to tensorflow from pip list,
tensorboard-data-server      0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow-estimator         2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.29.0
tflite-runtime               2.5.0.post1

searching through google i have not found an answer to solve this warning.
when checking the sources.list from /etc/apt
multistrap-bsp.list>>
deb [arch=arm64] https://mendel-linux.org/apt/eagle-bsp-enterprise eagle main
deb-src https://mendel-linux.org/apt/eagle-bsp-enterprise eagle main

multistrap-edgetpu.list>>>
deb [arch=arm64] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable main
deb-src https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt 
coral-edgetpu-stable main

